# Use content and create own font awesomes without using any dependency or link into html

Tags: css, font-awesome

Can we use content in css to create our own icons if we do not require any dependency or cdn path added into the html?
There is a small requirement of single page application which I don't need to add dependencies and any other external css into it.
If there is any possibility help me out!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a data url in the content so it's all within the stylesheet.

Here's a trivial example:

```css
div::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='90' height='45'%3E%3Cpath d='M10 10h60' stroke='%2300F' stroke-width='5'/%3E%3Cpath d='M10 20h60' stroke='%230F0' stroke-width='5'/%3E%3Cpath d='M10 30h60' stroke='red' stroke-width='5'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```